# Persistance with an ARWorldMap created with ARKit through Unity

Tags: swift, objective-c, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am new to AR and using Unity, ARFoundation, and ARKit.

Will my `ARWorldMap`s have persistence in an outdoor or indoor experience and will it be as effective as Azure? I will only be deploying on iOS so cross-platform is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving ARWorldMap is not a rocket science. If this feature is supported in ARKit extension for Unity, ARWorldMap will be saved in any AR app the same way as expected. The main difference is that Unity builds for iOS are written in **slow** Objective-C, not in **faster** Swift for UIKit, and not in the **fastest** Swift for SwiftUI. In iOS for storing ARWorldMap you must use `NSKeyedArchiver`, and for retrieving ARWorldMap data you must use `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

```swift
func writeWorldMap(_ worldMap: ARWorldMap, to url: URL) throws {

    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap, 
                                         requiringSecureCoding: true)
    try data.write(to: url)
}
```

ARWorldMap stores world coordinate grid, position and orientation of your device, reference snapshots of a surrounding environment and ARAnchors. It's hard to say what you mean saying *`...as effective as Azure...`* but ARWorldMap data is the most effective offline way to store and retrieve persistence data in iOS AR apps.

Comment: perfect.  I may not have the option to work in swift.  Is there a noticeable difference with speed.?  I can switch to RealityKit just concerned about the functionality with audio.

Comment: If AR app is simple (written in several lines of code), the difference in speed is negligible. However, even simple SwiftUI apps start faster.